# Why won't echo a variable?

Tags: php, html

Trying to echo `$data`... it prints nothing after data is sent to `$citystate` and `$address`?

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

  $zillow_id = 'X1-ZWz18i4rtwj56z_8xo7s'; //the zillow web service ID that you got from your email

  $search = $_GET['address'];
  $citystate = $_GET['citystate'];
  $address = urlencode($search);
  $citystatezip = urlencode($citystate);

  $url = "http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm?zws-id=$zillow_id&address=$address&citystatezip=$citystatezip";

  $result = file_get_contents($url);
  $data = simplexml_load_string($result);

  echo $data->response->results->result[0]->zpid;

?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br>
City, State, ZIP: <input type="text" name="citystate"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If there's a WP plugin that does this too, that'd be nice. But I'm still curious.

Comment: What is `$data`? Do `var_dump($data);`.

Comment: address = ? and citystate = ?

Comment: I'm quite sure of two things, **1** you have errors disabled. **2** $data does not hold the values you think it does.

Comment: I get Error: invalid or missing city/state/ZIP parameter so the form isn't submitting the data or I'm sending it to the wrong variables? address = $search no?

Comment: No Nigel Ren. Thanks though.

Comment: You need to look  into how a form is submitted and then use the $_POST values to link to the address value you send.

Comment: can you provide any sample data for api ?

Answer (score 0):

API does not return any data if data is wrong so you have to add right parameters in URL.

check this link - Try below url 
http://example.com/?zws-id=X1-ZWz18i4rtwj56z_8xo7s&address=2114+Bigelow+Ave&citystate=Seattle%2C+WA it return data and show zpid

**Result: 48749425**

Check zillow API full data here - http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm?zws-id=X1-ZWz18i4rtwj56z_8xo7s&address=2114+Bigelow+Ave&citystatezip=Seattle%2C+WA